# Application lifecycle events with spring?

Tags: java, spring

Establishing connections to external systems (databases etc) as part of the spring context construction seems like bad idea. Does the framework contain any method for actual application lifecycle management ? Since I'm running in embedded-mode, my best suggestion yet is to use a ListableBeanFactory to get all the beans and make an interface with start/stop/isRunning on all the application beans. Do I have to roll my own or is there something within spring I can use ?

Comment: You could implement the [`Lifecycle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) or [`SmartLifecycle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html). Which already provide those methods :) and which will make it spring managed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring has the [`Lifecycle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Lifecycle.html) interface which you can implement. This interface provides basic `start`, `stop` and `isRunning` methods.

You could also implement the [`SmartLifecycle`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/SmartLifecycle.html) interface which allows for a little more control over when something is invoked due the the additional [`Phased`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/Phased.html) interface.

See also [How does Lifecycle interface work in Spring? What are "top-level singleton beans"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551408/how-does-lifecycle-interface-work-in-spring-what-are-top-level-singleton-beans) and [Load spring context in phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339524/load-spring-context-in-phases).